# Google adMob without unit ID(AdMob publisher ID), just for testing

Tags: android, admob, ads, adsense

Is there some way to test adMob in my android application, without having to sign up for it? I first want to test it, before paying to get one. Maybe with some 'general' ID, or some other trick?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize adMob was free. I'll also take a look at your suggestions. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admob is free, you don't have to pay to sign up and test but you will need to sign up to put ads in your app, even test ads.

Also I found Mobclix better IMO.

Answer (score 4):

ADmob is free!!! :D. just go and make yourself an account. you cant do it without an id.